# Failure to build apk and app bundle for my app project in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-apk

I finally creating an apk/aab file for the app that i need to upload in google play console when suddenly it print an error "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. " so after google for answer i follow the flutter guide on how to proper build and release but after completing all the instruction i can run the app in the vs code but when building an apk if failed and here is the log

"* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)"

i cant find any solution please help me

Comment: Have you added `keystore.properties file`?

Comment: Please follow this for generate signed build or bundle : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android . if its still failing then post error here

Comment: how to i add keystore.properties file?

Comment: kindly follow all the steps in the link which is given by @HardikMehta. Then you'll not face any issue.

Comment: thank you for all your help, i miss one thing in that instruction which is create a key.properties file thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Create jks with normal generate build flow like android and use it as a .jks
or type this common in your terminal

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias aliasname -storetype JKS
```

For instance:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Users/mac/Desktop/Playstore_Live/appname.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias uploadAlias -storetype JKS
```

fill all Detail it will ask for

Reference the keystore from the app
Create a file named [project]/android/key.properties that contains a reference to your keystore:
Copy and paste in key.properties

```
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=<Alias name from previous step> // uploadAlias
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks>
```

Warning: Keep the key.properties file private; don’t check it into public source control.
Configure signing in gradle

COPY AND PASTE IN  [project]/android/app/build.gradle file  before the android block.

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
      ...
}
```

And replace it with the following signing configuration info:content_copy

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
 }
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }
```

}

Create Build

- flutter build apk --no-shrink
- flutter build apk --release
- flutter build appbundle